# My Clear JButton seems to disable my calculation Receipt JButton and doesn't cleared the JRadioButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

The CLEAR button doesnt clear the JRadiobutton in my code.It also affects my Receipt button in ActionPerformed which makes the textArea for Receipt displaying only the lines outside the JCheckBox blocks.It seems that the Clear button disable the Receipt button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getSource() == btnReceipt)
    {
        double totD = 0.0, totalS = 0.0, totalU = 0.0, totalP = 0.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double totP = 0.0;
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\t\tWELCOME TO SUPER TUITION CENTER SDN BHD" + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("CUSTOMER'S NAME:" + txtname.getText() + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("AGE\t              :" + txtage.getText() + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("CONTACT NO             :" + txtcontact.getText() + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("SUBJECTS :         " + "\t\t PRICE" + "\tHOUR" + "\tTIME" + "\tTOTAL" + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        if (rbUpsr.isSelected())
        {
            int countU = 0;
            double totbm1 = 0.0, totbm2 = 0.0, totbi = 0.0, totmath = 0.0, totsc = 0.0;

            if (cbUbm1.isSelected())
            {
                int hrbm1 = Integer.parseInt(txtUh1.getText());
                int tmbm1 = Integer.parseInt(txtUt1.getText());
                totbm1 = 20 * hrbm1 * tmbm1;
                countU++;
                txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU PEMAHAMAN " + "\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrbm1 + "\t" + tmbm1 + "\t" + df.format(totbm1) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbUbm2.isSelected())
            {
                int hrbm2 = Integer.parseInt(txtUh2.getText());
                int tmbm2 = Integer.parseInt(txtUt2.getText());
                totbm2 = 20 * hrbm2 * tmbm2;
                countU++;
                txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU PENULISAN " + "\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrbm2 + "\t" + tmbm2 + "\t" + df.format(totbm2) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbUbi.isSelected())
            {
                int hrbi = Integer.parseInt(txtUh3.getText());
                int tmbi = Integer.parseInt(txtUt3.getText());
                totbi = 20 * hrbi * tmbi;
                countU++;
                txtReceipt.append("BAHASA INGGERIS          " + "\t\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrbi + "\t" + tmbi + "\t" + df.format(totbi) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbUmath.isSelected())
            {
                int hrmath = Integer.parseInt(txtUh4.getText());
                int tmmath = Integer.parseInt(txtUt4.getText());
                totmath = 20 * hrmath * tmmath;
                countU++;
                txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK                " + "\t\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrmath + "\t" + tmmath + "\t" + df.format(totmath) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbUsc.isSelected())
            {
                int hrsc = Integer.parseInt(txtUh5.getText());
                int tmsc = Integer.parseInt(txtUt5.getText());
                totsc = 20 * hrsc * tmsc;
                txtReceipt.append("SAINS                    " + "\t\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrsc + "\t" + tmsc + "\t" + df.format(totsc) + "\n"); // set to text area
                countU++;
            }
            totalU = totbm1 + totbm2 + totbi + totmath + totsc;
            if (countU > 5)
            {
                totD = totalU * 0.1;
                totP = totalU - totD;
            }
            else
            {
                totP = totalU;
            }
            txtReceipt.append("TOTAL FEES : " + "\t\t" + "RM" + totalU + "0" + "\n");
        }

        if (rbPt3.isSelected())
        {

            double pbm = 0.0, pbi = 0.0, pm3 = 0.0, psc = 0.0, pag = 0.0, psj = 0.0, pkh = 0.0;
            int countP = 0;

            if (cbPbm.isSelected())
            {
                int textPhbm = Integer.parseInt(txtPhbm.getText());
                int textPtbm = Integer.parseInt(txtPtbm.getText());
                pbm = 35 * textPhbm * textPtbm;
                countP++;
                txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU            " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhbm + "\t  " + textPtbm + "\t  " + df.format(pbm) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbPbi.isSelected())
            {
                int textPhbi = Integer.parseInt(txtPhbi.getText());
                int textPtbi = Integer.parseInt(txtPtbi.getText());
                pbi = 35 * textPhbi * textPtbi;
                countP++;
                txtReceipt.append("BAHASA INGGERIS          " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhbi + "\t  " + textPtbi + "\t  " + df.format(pbi) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbPm3.isSelected())
            {
                int textPhm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtPhm3.getText());
                int textPtm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtPtm3.getText());
                pm3 = 35 * textPhm3 * textPtm3;
                countP++;
                txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK                " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhm3 + "\t  " + textPtm3 + "\t  " + df.format(pm3) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbPsc.isSelected())
            {
                int textPhsc = Integer.parseInt(txtPhsc.getText());
                int textPtsc = Integer.parseInt(txtPtsc.getText());
                psc = 35 * textPhsc * textPtsc;
                countP++;
                txtReceipt.append("SAINS                    " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhsc + "\t  " + textPtsc + "\t  " + df.format(psc) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbPag.isSelected())
            {
                int textPhag = Integer.parseInt(txtPhag.getText());
                int textPtag = Integer.parseInt(txtPtag.getText());
                pag = 35 * textPhag * textPtag;
                countP++;
                txtReceipt.append("PENDIDIKAN ISLAM         " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhag + "\t  " + textPtag + "\t  " + df.format(pag) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbPsj.isSelected())
            {
                int textPhsj = Integer.parseInt(txtPhsj.getText());
                int textPtsj = Integer.parseInt(txtPtsj.getText());
                psj = 35 * textPhsj * textPtsj;
                countP++;
                txtReceipt.append("SEJARAH                  " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhsj + "\t  " + textPtsj + "\t  " + df.format(psj) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }
            if (cbPkh.isSelected())
            {
                int textPhkh = Integer.parseInt(txtPhkh.getText());
                int textPtkh = Integer.parseInt(txtPtkh.getText());
                pkh = 35 * textPhkh * textPtkh;
                countP++;
                txtReceipt.append("KEMAHIRAN HIDUP          " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhkh + "\t  " + textPtkh + "\t  " + df.format(pkh) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            totalP = pbm + pbi + pm3 + psc + pag + psj + pkh;

            if (countP >= 6)
            {
                totD = totalP * 0.1;
                totP = totalP - totD;
            }
            else
            {
                totP = totalP;
            }
            txtReceipt.append("TOTAL FEES : " + "\t\t" + "RM" + totalP + "0" + "\n");//set to textArea

        }

        if (rbSpm.isSelected())
        {
            double bm = 0.0, bi = 0.0, ag = 0.0, sej = 0.0, m3 = 0.0, addm3 = 0.0, sc = 0.0, cm = 0.0, bio = 0.0, fz = 0.0, ac = 0.0, pd = 0.0;
            int countS = 0;

            if (cbSbm.isSelected())
            {
                int hbm = Integer.parseInt(txtShbm.getText());
                int tbm = Integer.parseInt(txtStbm.getText());
                bm = 50 * hbm * tbm;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hbm + "\t   " + tbm + "\t   " + df.format(bm) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSbi.isSelected())
            {
                int hbi = Integer.parseInt(txtShbi.getText());
                int tbi = Integer.parseInt(txtStbi.getText());
                bi = 50 * hbi * tbi;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("BAHASA INGGERIS         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hbi + "\t   " + tbi + "\t   " + df.format(bi) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSag.isSelected())
            {
                int hag = Integer.parseInt(txtShag.getText());
                int tag = Integer.parseInt(txtStag.getText());
                ag = 50 * hag * tag;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("PENDIDIKAN ISLAM         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hag + "\t   " + tag + "\t   " + df.format(ag) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSsej.isSelected())
            {
                int hsej = Integer.parseInt(txtShsej.getText());
                int tsej = Integer.parseInt(txtStsej.getText());
                sej = 50 * hsej * tsej;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("SEJARAH         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hsej + "\t   " + tsej + "\t   " + df.format(sej) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSm3.isSelected())
            {
                int hm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtShm3.getText());
                int tm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtStm3.getText());
                m3 = 50 * hm3 * tm3;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hm3 + "\t   " + tm3 + "\t   " + df.format(m3) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSaddm3.isSelected())
            {
                int haddm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtShaddm3.getText());
                int taddm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtStaddm3.getText());
                addm3 = 50 * haddm3 * taddm3;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK TAMBAHAN " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + haddm3 + "\t   " + taddm3 + "\t   " + df.format(addm3) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSsc.isSelected())
            {
                int hsc = Integer.parseInt(txtShsc.getText());
                int tsc = Integer.parseInt(txtStsc.getText());
                sc = 50 * hsc * tsc;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("SAINS         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hsc + "\t   " + tsc + "\t   " + df.format(sc) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbScm.isSelected())
            {
                int hcm = Integer.parseInt(txtShcm.getText());
                int tcm = Integer.parseInt(txtStcm.getText());
                cm = 50 * hcm * tcm;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("KIMIA         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hcm + "\t   " + tcm + "\t   " + df.format(cm) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSbio.isSelected())
            {
                int hbio = Integer.parseInt(txtShbio.getText());
                int tbio = Integer.parseInt(txtStbio.getText());
                bio = 50 * hbio * tbio;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("BIOLOGI" + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hbio + "\t   " + tbio + "\t   " + df.format(bio) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSfz.isSelected())
            {
                int hfz = Integer.parseInt(txtShfz.getText());
                int tfz = Integer.parseInt(txtStfz.getText());
                fz = 50 * hfz * tfz;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("FIZIK         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hfz + "\t   " + tfz + "\t   " + df.format(fz) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSac.isSelected())
            {
                int hac = Integer.parseInt(txtShac.getText());
                int tac = Integer.parseInt(txtStac.getText());
                ac = 50 * hac * tac;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("AKAUN         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hac + "\t   " + tac + "\t   " + df.format(ac) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            if (cbSpd.isSelected())
            {
                int hpd = Integer.parseInt(txtShpd.getText());
                int tpd = Integer.parseInt(txtStpd.getText());
                pd = 50 * hpd * tpd;
                countS++;
                txtReceipt.append("PERDAGANGAN" + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hpd + "\t   " + tpd + "\t   " + df.format(pd) + "\n"); // set to text area
            }

            totalS = bm + bi + ag + sej + m3 + addm3 + sc + cm + fz + ac + pd;

            if (countS >= 6)
            {
                totD = totalS * 0.1;
                totP = totalS - totD;
            }
            else
            {
                totP = totalS;
            }
            txtReceipt.append("TOTAL FEES : " + "\t\t" + "RM" + totP + "0" + "\n");
        }



        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("TOTAL DISCOUNT : " + "\t\t" + "RM " + totD + "0" + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("TOTAL PAYMENT PER MONTH : " + "\t" + "RM" + (totP * 4) + "0" + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\t  THANK YOU FOR CHOOSING SUPER TUITION SDN BHD" + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n"); // set to text area
    }
    else 
    if (event.getSource() == btnClear)
    {
        cbUbm1.setSelected(false);
        cbUbm2.setSelected(false);
        cbUbi.setSelected(false);
        cbUmath.setSelected(false);
        cbUsc.setSelected(false);

        txtUh1.setText(" ");
        txtUh2.setText(" ");
        txtUh3.setText(" ");
        txtUh4.setText(" ");
        txtUh5.setText(" ");

        txtUt1.setText(" ");
        txtUt2.setText(" ");
        txtUt3.setText(" ");
        txtUt4.setText(" ");
        txtUt5.setText(" ");

        txtPhbm.setText(" ");
        txtPhbi.setText(" ");
        txtPhm3.setText(" ");
        txtPhsc.setText(" ");
        txtPhag.setText(" ");
        txtPhsj.setText(" ");
        txtPhkh.setText(" ");
        txtPtbm.setText(" ");
        txtPtbi.setText(" ");
        txtPtm3.setText(" ");
        txtPtsc.setText(" ");
        txtPtag.setText(" ");
        txtPtsj.setText(" ");
        txtPtkh.setText(" ");


        cbPbm.setSelected(false);
        cbPbi.setSelected(false);
        cbPm3.setSelected(false);
        cbPsc.setSelected(false);
        cbPag.setSelected(false);
        cbPsj.setSelected(false);
        cbPkh.setSelected(false);




        txtShbm.setText(" ");
        txtShbi.setText(" ");
        txtShsc.setText(" ");
        txtShag.setText(" ");
        txtShm3.setText(" ");
        txtShac.setText(" ");
        txtShpd.setText(" ");
        txtShaddm3.setText(" ");
        txtShcm.setText(" ");
        txtShbio.setText(" ");
        txtShfz.setText(" ");
        txtShsej.setText(" ");

        txtStbm.setText(" ");
        txtStbi.setText(" ");
        txtStsc.setText(" ");
        txtStag.setText(" ");
        txtStm3.setText(" ");
        txtStac.setText(" ");
        txtStpd.setText(" ");
        txtStaddm3.setText(" ");
        txtStcm.setText(" ");
        txtStbio.setText(" ");
        txtStfz.setText(" ");
        txtStsej.setText(" ");

        cbSbm.setSelected(false);
        cbSbi.setSelected(false);
        cbSsc.setSelected(false);
        cbSag.setSelected(false);
        cbSm3.setSelected(false);
        cbSac.setSelected(false);
        cbSpd.setSelected(false);
        cbSaddm3.setSelected(false);
        cbScm.setSelected(false);
        cbSbio.setSelected(false);
        cbSfz.setSelected(false);
        cbSsej.setSelected(false);
        txtname.setText(" ");
        txtage.setText(" ");
        txtcontact.setText(" ");

        rbUpsr.setSelected(false);
        rbPt3.setSelected(false);
        rbSpm.setSelected(false);
        txtReceipt.setText("\t  WELCOME TO SUPER TUITION SDN BHD\t\t" + "\n"); //clearing all data that are available
    }    


    else if (event.getSource() == btnExit)
    {
        System.exit(0); //exit the program
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question without the possibility to see and debug your code. So if you want go get an an answer, please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Probably during your work on SSCCE you'll find your problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> The CLEAR button doesnt clear the JRadiobutton in my code.

A radio button must be selected. If you want to clear all the buttons then you need to use:

```
buttonModel.clear();
```

Read the `ButtonModel.clear()` API for more information.